# Append contents of file A to the end of each line in file B? bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I really can't get this one.

File A has this:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

etc..

File B will always have the exact same amount of lines and they always will correspond:

```
oneoneoneone
twotwotwotwo
3ee3ee3ee3ee
```

I want to append file A to file B so it looks like:

```
1.1.1.1 oneoneoneone
2.2.2.2 twotwotwotwo
3.3.3.3 3ee3ee3ee3ee
```

This is what I have but not working like  it should:

for z in `cat /tmp/fileB; do sed "s/(.*)/\1$z/" < /tmp/fileA >> /tmp/c;done

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to append the lines in fileB to the lines in fileA (as indicated by your desired output), you can simply do:

```
paste fileA fileB
```

That uses a tab for the delimeter, so you might prefer

```
paste -d ' ' fileA fileB
```

If you want to do it with `awk`, you can do:

```
awk '{ getline b < "fileB"; print $0, b}' fileA
```

This may be possible with `sed`, but it's not advisable.  Similar to what you seem to be trying with the loop, you can also do:

```
while read b; do read -u 4 a; echo $a $b; done < fileb 4< filea
```